# How It possible to join two tables in sql with different param

Tags: sql

I try to explain better my question with an example.

I have two tables :

**Names**:

```
id  (pk)
name 
lang (fk)
comment
```

Table **lang**:

```
id (pk)
name
```

I would to create a query that show every name of lang that haven't got any names.name and for any lang show the number of the name that have this lang .

```
SELECT lang.name, names.name
FROM lang 
FULL JOIN names ON lang.id = names.lang
WHERE names.name IS NULL
```

This query show two columns but in the second column (names.name) I would like to show the number of names that have the lang specified in the rows of the first column .

I hope that I explain well the problem and I would to know how it possible to show two different tables united in one

Comment: Please edit your question and show sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT l.name, COUNT(n.name) as numNames
FROM lang l LEFT JOIN
     names n
     ON l.id = n.lang
GROUP BY l.name;
```

When `numNames` is 0, then there are no names with that language.

Comment: thanks gordon that work well ,I think that the problem is to use the count function without group by, your answer is the best but I can't vote because I haven't enough votes